# Virutalizing a physical machine with a DRM software

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vmware, hardware-virtualization, drm

I have a software on an old Windows 7 machine that checks if it's running on the host machine as its means of DRM protection against piracy, e.g. checking the hard drive UUID. Is it possible to virtualize the physical machine containing the software so this software can still function properly?

I am afraid that at some point the physical drive may fail and I will not be able to use the software any longer.

Comment: You may want to mention the software in question, as its possible for different DRM schemes to work differently (I had some software which checked the MAC addresses of the system.)  Hard drive UUID's can be changed, but things which use the check using the TPM module are harder or maybe impossible to virtualize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to try and see, but the feasibility of the project depends on what
that product checks.

Disk serials will usually be kept by P2V.

The network MAC you may need to reset to be the same, and you will need to keep
the original computer off the network when testing.
Or you may test (on another computer) using a host-only virtual network adapter
that is available on most virtualization software.

Some components are by necessity passed as-is to the virtual machine,
which may include the CPU and GPU (depending on the virtualization software).

So just try. If it doesn't work, you can trace the execution of the product using
[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon),
which might indicate what is the last information system call that it did,
then search for methods of faking it.